# WordPress: if post time is after a specific date

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress

I'm trying to add to this if statement another one that checks if post time is before a specific date (let's say 14th March 2014..).

```
<?php if (in_category('5')) {
    echo 'something'; }
?>
```

I tried with this but it's echoed even on posts newer than that date

```
<?php
    $date1 = "2014-03-14";
    $date2 = $post->post_date;
    if ( (in_category('5')) && ($date1 < $date2) ) {
        echo 'something';
    }
```

?>

Comment: At 800 rep you are absolutely expected to know how to format your code so that people here can actually give a darn about helping you...

Comment: Indentation is personal and intimate :P

Comment: Yes and I intimately suggest indentation because it is personal to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd convert your dates to timestamps first to make them easier to compare.

```
global $post;
$compare_date = strtotime( "2014-03-14" );
$post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );

if ( in_category(5) && ( $compare_date > $post_date ) ) ...
```

It looks like you have your operator the wrong way round as well. You wanted to check if posts are before the date. The post date would have to be smaller to be before. Also you're passing in category ID 5 as a string for some reason which I corrected in my code above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) The problem is that now nothing's echoed, before and after that date.. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EpjL9UyT
No error in logs.

Comment: I'd suggest doing it without the category check to be sure

Comment: You haven't given a condition for after that date so nothing could be echoed. Add an else to your if.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nathan, his answer worked great for me.

```
global $post;
$compare_date = strtotime( "2016-07-14" );
$post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );

if ( in_category(2) && ( $compare_date >= $post_date ) ) { 
    echo "On or before July 14."
} else { 
    echo "After July 14."
}
```